# Pythonanywhere static files mapping - when does it kick in?

Tags: pythonanywhere

I have a django instance set up on pythonanywhere.

I have debug turned off in my settings

I have a STATIC_ROOT setting of  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "allstatic").

I have set up the static files mapping in the Web section of my pythonanywhere console

```
URL = /allstatic/ 
Directory = /home/username/project/allstatic
```

(I'm calling it allstatic so I can tell that the files are coming from the mapping)

I have run collectstatic and /allstatic has files in it.

I am using {% static 'folder/file' %} in my templates

And with all this - the static files were all being delivered.  However, when I checked the page source HTML, they all appeared to be coming from '/static' So I wasn't sure if they were being delivered by the more efficient console driven mapping.

When I changed 'STATIC_URL' setting to 'allstatic' the html shows '/allstatic' and the files still load. BUt I'm not sure how to tell if my mapping is working.

To use a concrete example

I have an app called 'universal' in django, with the following structure

```
 universal
     static
         universal
             img
                 logo.png
```

In my local dev environment, with debugging on, this shows up as `/static/universal/img/logo.png`

However, in my prod environment with debugging off and all the above steps taken, this *also* shows up as `/static/universal/img/logo.png` - until I set the STATIC_URL to allstatic

How can I be sure I am using the allstatic mapping I set in the pythonanywhere console? And does STATIC_URL affect whether I am using it or not?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but you can check urls that your static files are downloaded from in the dev tools in your browser.

Comment: It maybe a margin-note, but you need to remember about the extra step on PythonAnywhere, which is setting static files mappings on the Web page.  See also: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingStaticFiles/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

In order to test that the web console static mapping is working on pythonanywhere, I made the following setting explicit and then commented out AppDirectoriesFinder

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
```

This ensures that app directories aren't being looked at to find static files - it will require the Web Console page mapping (or an entry in STATICFILES_DIRS which is empty by default) to be set up correctly to find files.

Doing this I was able to find that my previous STATIC_URL setting of 'static/' rather than 'allstatic/' had in fact been failing to use the mapping - something previously obscured by the fact that both /static/universal/img/logo.png and /allstatic/universal/img/logo.png seemed to work.

(It's interesting that the app level /static locations still work on pythonanywhere with debug turned off - I suspect this fact was muddling me a bit).